# Nginx auth basic won't work for wordpress wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, nginx, .htpasswd

I have used several rules to block wp-login.php with a htpassword. The htpassword module is working. I added it to root of the site and it worked. But wp-login.php is not working. Here's my website `http://www.digitalreborn.com/wp-admin`

Here's the passwd rule :

```
location ~* /wp-login.php {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area: WordPress";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/digitalreborn/.htpasswd;

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$ htpasswd -bc /tmp/secure_admin.txt admin password
```

Then on your nginx virtual host conf.

```
location ^~ /wp-login.php {
    auth_basic           "Restricted Area: WordPress";
    auth_basic_user_file /tmp/secure_admin.txt;
}
```

Then restart the service:

```
$ service nginx restart
```

---

403 Forbidden after correct login:

> This can be caused by permissions or a non-existent or invalid
>   directory index directive.

Comment: Now it prompts for password but after entering the password it say 403 Forbidden

Comment: @EApubs did you add `index index.php` on your index block in your root location?

Comment: It worked! I added the php rules back and now its working. Thanks!